# numpy.int64' object is not callable

Tags: python

I'm trying to use Unscented Kalman Filter but it is showing this error.

File "plotter.py", line 15, in 
    (filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = ukf.filter(measurements)

TypeError: 'numpy.int64' object is not callable

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.pyplot import plot
from numpy import array,asarray
from pykalman import UnscentedKalmanFilter

data = pd.read_csv('imu.csv')

F = array([[1.0,-0.006],[0,1]])
H = array([[1,0]])
Q = array([[1 ,0],[0 ,1]])
R = 10
measurements = asarray([data.Acc_X])
ukf = UnscentedKalmanFilter(transition_functions = 
F,observation_functions = H,transition_covariance = Q, 
observation_covariance = R,initial_state_mean = 
array([0,0]),initial_state_covariance = array([[10,0],[0,10]]))
(filtered_state_means, filtered_state_covariances) = 
ukf.filter(measurements)
(smoothed_state_means, smoothed_state_covariances) = 
ukf.smooth(measurements)
plot(data.Number,smoothed_state_means[:,1])
raw_input()
```

Comment: The doc tell us that `UnscentedKalmanFilter` requires `transition_functions` and `observation_functions` to be function or array of functions. You are passing arrays https://pykalman.github.io/#unscentedkalmanfilter

Comment: Thanks that helped